# API of Kubernetes in java: authentication error

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I am developing a simple java app that show the pods of the cluster.

This is the app:

```
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.Configuration;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Pod;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1PodList;
import io.kubernetes.client.util.ClientBuilder;
import io.kubernetes.client.util.KubeConfig;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * A simple example of how to use the Java API from an application outside a kubernetes cluster
 *
 * <p>Easiest way to run this: mvn exec:java
 * -Dexec.mainClass="io.kubernetes.client.examples.KubeConfigFileClientExample"
 *
 */
public class untitled4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ApiException {

        // file path to your KubeConfig
        String kubeConfigPath = "/home/robin/.kube/config";

        // loading the out-of-cluster config, a kubeconfig from file-system
        ApiClient client =
                ClientBuilder.kubeconfig(KubeConfig.loadKubeConfig(new FileReader(kubeConfigPath))).build();

        // set the global default api-client to the in-cluster one from above
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

        // the CoreV1Api loads default api-client from global configuration.
        CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();

        // invokes the CoreV1Api client
        V1PodList list = api.listPodForAllNamespaces(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        System.out.println("Listing all pods: ");
        for (V1Pod item : list.getItems()) {
            System.out.println(item.getMetadata().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unimplemented
    at io.kubernetes.client.util.authenticators.GCPAuthenticator.refresh(GCPAuthenticator.java:61)
    at io.kubernetes.client.util.KubeConfig.getAccessToken(KubeConfig.java:215)
    at io.kubernetes.client.util.credentials.KubeconfigAuthentication.<init>(KubeconfigAuthentication.java:46)
    at io.kubernetes.client.util.ClientBuilder.kubeconfig(ClientBuilder.java:276)
    at untitled4.main(untitled4.java:28)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/issues/290) on **GitHub** related with this problem. For now you can use workarounds like the one, proposed by [jhbae200](https://github.com/jhbae200) in [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/issues/290#issuecomment-480205118):

> I am using it like this.
>
> ```
> package kubernetes.gcp;
>
> import com.google.auth.oauth2.AccessToken;
> import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
> import io.kubernetes.client.util.KubeConfig;
> import io.kubernetes.client.util.authenticators.Authenticator;
> import org.slf4j.Logger;
> import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
>
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.time.Instant;
> import java.util.Date;
> import java.util.Map;
>
> public class ReplacedGCPAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
>     private static final Logger log;
>     private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "access-token";
>     private static final String EXPIRY = "expiry";
>
>     static {
>         log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(io.kubernetes.client.util.authenticators.GCPAuthenticator.class);
>     }
>
>     private final GoogleCredentials credentials;
>
>     public ReplacedGCPAuthenticator(GoogleCredentials credentials) {
>         this.credentials = credentials;
>     }
>
>     public String getName() {
>         return "gcp";
>     }
>
>     public String getToken(Map<String, Object> config) {
>         return (String) config.get("access-token");
>     }
>
>     public boolean isExpired(Map<String, Object> config) {
>         Object expiryObj = config.get("expiry");
>         Instant expiry = null;
>         if (expiryObj instanceof Date) {
>             expiry = ((Date) expiryObj).toInstant();
>         } else if (expiryObj instanceof Instant) {
>             expiry = (Instant) expiryObj;
>         } else {
>             if (!(expiryObj instanceof String)) {
>                 throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected object type: " + expiryObj.getClass());
>             }
>
>             expiry = Instant.parse((String) expiryObj);
>         }
>
>         return expiry != null && expiry.compareTo(Instant.now()) <= 0;
>     }
>
>     public Map<String, Object> refresh(Map<String, Object> config) {
>         try {
>             AccessToken accessToken = this.credentials.refreshAccessToken();
>
>             config.put(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken.getTokenValue());
>             config.put(EXPIRY, accessToken.getExpirationTime());
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             throw new RuntimeException(e);
>         }
>         return config;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Running in.
>
> ```
> //GoogleCredentials.fromStream(--something credential.json filestream--)
> KubeConfig.registerAuthenticator(new ReplacedGCPAuthenticator(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()));
> ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
> Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);
> CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
> V1PodList list = api.listNamespacedPod("default", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 30, Boolean.FALSE);
> for (V1Pod item : list.getItems()) {
>     System.out.println(item.getMetadata().getName());
> }
> ```